# How do I sort and merge data (in Excel) with hexadecimal codes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, merge, hexadecimal

I take attendance in large, lecture classes.  Each student inputs a vote on a multiple-choice question with a "clicker" (a hand-held, remote control device), and each clicker has a 6-digit, hexadecimal serial number.  This semester, I have been placing the attendance data into an Excel spreadsheet (sorting hexadecimal numbers is a nightmare, but that's another story).  Due to students' absences, the list of serial codes is different---and has a different size---for different days.  Therefore, I have been manually checking off on attendance by visually looking for the same serial numbers.

Can you suggest a way to have Excel automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is all in columns in a single worksheet, use `=countif()` on a new worksheet where you have:

- column A Student Name
- column B Student Hexcode
- column C `=countif(reference to the column in the other sheet, cell to the left)`

This would give you a count of attendance for students to compare to the number of classes held so far.

Alternatively if the data for each class is in a separate worksheet (either in a single workbook, or multiple workbooks:

- column A Student Name
- column B Student Hexcode
- column C-X (one for each class) `=match(cell with Hexcode, range for this class, false)`